# awesomewm tags repeat endlessly

Tags: lua, awesome-wm

I just upgraded to awesome 4.3 and after I open a couple of apps my tags start repeating endlessly. I use alpha characters instead of numbers or names, I can get 26 tags with a single keystroke shortcut, but the code is basically the same and has been working for over a year. After the update, this started for some reason, Chrome doesn't affect it, but if I open a couple of Thunars or my IDE's which is Java-based this starts. Within a few seconds, each screen sequentially will add another copy of the tags and it will continue endlessly. It also once this starts locks up the screen. Any help, ideas would be greatly appreciated, I can only work off the default config so it has slowed me down quite a bit. Thanks

```
local keyNames = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z" }
```

and the part where I add in the tags

```
awful.tag(keyNames, s, awful.layout.layouts[layoutIndex])
```

here is output from awmtt when I start it, when the problem occurs this portion of code also repeats in the console.

```
~/.config/awesome >>> awmtt start -S 2048x1280                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            ±[●●][master]
/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon
1936
2059
/usr/bin/start-pulseaudio-x11
3108
/usr/lib/mate-polkit/polkit-mate-authentication-agent-1
36875
/usr/bin/xfce4-power-manager
36881
/usr/bin/system-config-printer-applet
5409
/usr/bin/xfsettingsd
36891
/usr/bin/light-locker
2020-08-18 01:09:10 W: awesome: a_glib_poll:437: Last main loop iteration took 0.110275 seconds! Increasing limit for this warning to that value.
36888
/usr/bin/compton
/usr/bin/thunar
[ 08/18/2020 01:09:10.094 open_config_file_at WARN ] This compositor has been renamed to "picom", the old config file paths is deprecated. Please replace the "compton"s in the path with "picom"
[ 08/18/2020 01:09:10.094 parse_config_libconfig WARN ] Option `no-dock-shadow` is deprecated, and will be removed. Please use the wintype option `shadow` of `dock` instead.
[ 08/18/2020 01:09:10.094 parse_config_libconfig WARN ] Option `no-dnd-shadow` is deprecated, and will be removed. Please use the wintype option `shadow` of `dnd` instead.
[ 08/18/2020 01:09:10.094 parse_config_libconfig WARN ] Option `menu-opacity` is deprecated, and will be removed.Please use the wintype option `opacity` of `popup_menu` and `dropdown_menu` instead.
[ 08/18/2020 01:09:10.094 parse_config_libconfig WARN ] vsync option will take a boolean from now on. "none" is interpreted as "false" for compatibility, but this will stop working soon
[ 08/18/2020 01:09:10.094 parse_config_libconfig WARN ] glx-swap-method has been deprecated since v6, your setting "undefined" should be replaced by `use-damage = true`.
[ 08/18/2020 01:09:10.094 parse_config_libconfig WARN ] "clear-shadow" is removed as an option, and is always enabled now. Consider removing it from your config file
[ 08/18/2020 01:09:10.094 parse_config_libconfig ERROR ] "paint-on-overlay" has been removed as an option, and the feature is enabled whenever possible
[ 08/18/2020 01:09:10.094 main FATAL ERROR ] Failed to create new session.
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, what I found out is during the upgrade discreet portions of my config got doubled. I used backups from prior to rebuild the config as close to current as possible and the problem went away. Thanks